# java script arrow functions

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

i made a button called btn and i gave it a text

```
btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.textContent = "Hello World"
```

i want to make it alert its textContent when it gets clicked.

i know i can use:

```
btn.onclick = function(){alert(this.textContent)}
```

but lately i have learnt about these arrow functions and i wanted to use it here so i made this

```
btn.onclick = ()=>{alert(this.textContent)}
```

and

```
btn.onclick = ()=> alert(this.textContent)
```

but both of them alert `undefined`

so how can i make it ?

Comment: Here's the most important thing: Arrow functions _do not have their own `this`_, they inherit the `this` from whatever context they were created in - like a variable only available in your function scope. In global context, this means `this` refers to the window, not the element. Read the docs for more info and detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: _“lately I have learnt about \[these\] arrow functions”_ — Where have you learned about being able to use `this` in an arrow function like that? Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) before using features you don’t really know how to use, and before asking.

Comment: sorry i meant i have heard about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` indicates its parent scope in arrow function, while it indicates button component in regular function. So in arrow function, you need to use `btn.textContent` instead of `this.textContent`

```js
btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.textContent = "Hello World"
// btn.onclick = function(){alert(this.textContent)}
btn.onclick = (event) => {alert(event.target.textContent)}
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```js
btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.textContent = "Hello World"
btn.onclick = function(){alert(this.textContent)}
// btn.onclick = (event) => {alert(event.target.textContent)}
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: This is only true because they were also defined in global scope. If you do `function(){ dom.onclick = () => console.log(this) }`, you will get a different object. Basically, `this` refers to whatever `this` referred to in the scope the arrow function was created.

Comment: yes, that means that the arrow function will have the scope of its parent.

Comment: I see you have now edited it :)

Comment: yes, I've edited it. thx for your info

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are not bound to a `this` object, as they act more like locally defined clumps of code you can run. This is why using `this` does not work - you created the arrow functions in the global context, where `this` was defined to refer to the `Window`. The way to solve this is to use another useful little detail: the `Event` argument:

```js
let i = 0;

document.body.onclick = event => event.target.textContent = i++;
```

```css
html,body { height: 100%; }
div { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div>0</div>
```

The event object can be used in this case, and it's better to use this record than to rely on a `this` here. `this` is mostly useful when you start creating prototypes and classes and need to refer to something internal. When they get bound to methods, it's a bit of a hodge-podgey mess to be certain which object it is referring to, and it's a bit complex, so better to use already provided values that you *know will always be correct*.